# Python app build with flatpak can not find package

Tags: python, packaging, flatpak

I'm trying to create a flatpak for our tool: https://github.com/IENT/RDPlot
My flatpak config and other files are here: https://github.com/IENT/flathub/tree/de.ient.RDPlot

When I try to call start the tool I get

```
flatpak-builder --run buildDir de.ient.RDPlot.yaml rdplot --filesystem=host                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/bin/rdplot", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-22.0.5-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-22.0.5-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-22.0.5-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-22.0.5-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 635, in _build_master
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-22.0.5-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 943, in require
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-22.0.5-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve

pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'sip' distribution was not found and is required by rdplot
```

I tried to set PYTHONPATH both locally before calling the command and in the flatpak config, but this did not work. 
I verified that the package was installed correctly:

```
cd  /var/lib/flatpak/app/de.ient.RDPlot/current/active/files/lib/python3.5/site-packages   
ipython
In [1]: import sip
In [2]: sip.__file__
Out[2]: '/var/lib/flatpak/app/de.ient.RDPlot/x86_64/master/028d157308e77fd7ea66c39d93bf661dc3ddebc570aae0bcad6f07ab92ae4257/files/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sip.so'
```

Any advice on how to proceed would be great! I noticed that other flatpaks, for example (https://github.com/flathub/org.kde.krita) patch sip, but they use a different sip/pyqt version and I don't really think its the same problem. I think it simply is not found.